# PythonWin pops up dialogue box when running .py file

Tags: python

When I run my something.py using PythonWin, I get this popup box: http://i.imgur.com/CCbMT24.png?1

I've never seen this before and it doesn't pop up for any of my other .py files.  It doesn't even let me run my something.py's functions like I normally can in the "Interactive Window".

All I want is to be able to run the individual functions in something.py for testing.  The only thing I changed before this popup issue was create  runsomething.py which will run something.py, but that seems irrelevant if I'm trying to only run something.py.

Does anyone know why this box pops up?

Comment: I had mistakenly added the line
    'import interact'
when investigating an issue with loading PythonWin

Answer (score 0):

The dialogue box pop up because of the line:

```
import interact
```